# Thinkpad X1 Extreme Intel UHD 630 Screen Tearing

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, thinkpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 Focal on my Thinkpad X1 Extreme Generation 1, and I immediately had screen tearing on my 1080p laptop screen with both my Intel UHD 630 graphics as well as my Nvidia 1050ti. I ensured I was using the Nvidia Proprietary Driver and followed this guide: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/fix-screen-tearing-ubuntu-18-04-optimus-laptops/
which took care of the screen tearing with the Nvidia Driver. The Intel graphics card however is still causing screen tearing! I can't find a solution that works. I ran this command in the terminal

```
$ inxi -G
```

This is what it returned:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
           unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.4
```

I already tried a 20-intel file with the tear-free option and it caused vertical purple lines to appear on the screen. I had to delete the file and reboot to remove the lines. What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my problem was not the graphics driver, it was Firefox (to test the tearing I was going to a Youtube video and watching a tearing test). To fix it I went to Firefox and typed in the URL:

about:config

I accepted the warning and searched:

layers.acceleration.force-enabled

I set that to True.